# Waiting till the QLineEdit text changes

Tags: c++, qt

I want to use QLineEdit to get an integer value that I want to work with. My problem is that I want to wait till the text is entered. It would also be nice if I can give a default text at the begining that will automatically be deleted after clicking on the QEditLine, like :
  [image]

for the first point I tried this and it didn't work:

```
 ......
int num =0;
QLineEdit *qtest = new QLineEdit();
........
mailayout->addWiget(qtest);// when I use the while loop the QLineEdit won't be added !! 
while(num ==0 ){
   num = qtest->text.toInt();
 }
.............
```

the program stays in the while loop, any Idea I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From the code you have posted, "num" will never be anything other than "0", so the loop will naturally continue on ad infinitum. You have to do something to make "num" different, like parse out a number from QLineEdit. CHEERS!

Comment: num will chage its value in the loop ??

Comment: @Engine No it won't, because the `QLineEdit` relies on the event queue for text to be entered in it, but the event queue can never be processed because the execution is stuck in the while loop.

Comment: @Engine You need to read up on signals and slots and also on the event loop. Otherwise you won't understand how to program for Qt.

Comment: All you need is to use the `editingFinished()` signal

Answer (score 6):

Use `setPlaceholderTest(const QString&)` for text to show when the user has not entered anything.

Don't poll the `QLineEdit` for changes, this is Qt so use signals.

```
connect( qtest, SIGNAL( editingFinished() ),
         someContainerObj, SLOT( myLineEditSlot() ) );
...
ContainerObj::myLineEditSlot()
{
    int num = qtest->text().toInt();
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer setPlaceholderText work but this second still doesn't work

Comment: How does it not work? How have you coded it?  Update your example code so we can see what you have done.

Comment: @Engine Did you even read what I said?  I suggest you follow satuon's advice because you are lacking in fundamental Qt knowledge.